# Missing MySQL client

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, git-bash

So I was following along with this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MX6wYbsUO-Y

It uses git.bash to install the mysql2 gem, and I'm stuck on the final step. The process he uses won't work for me, so instead, i just type:

```
gem install mysql2 -s http://rubygems.org
```

After this, it begins to work, but then it says the mysql client is missing:

```
    gem install mysql2-0.3.7.gem --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=X: --with-mysql-lib=X:\lib
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes

checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes

checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes

checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes

checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes

checking for rb_intern3()... yes

checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
-----
mysql client is missing. Check your installation of MySQL or Connector/C, and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I am very new to using mysql, and I don't even know where to begin, if anything, could anyone simply direct me to a resource where I could figure it out myself?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [download and install MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/) first.

If it's still not able to be found after you've installed it, supply the path on gem install.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please provide the version numbers when you are asking specific platform related questions

This is a 2 year old question but the problem still exists when starting ruby on windows

here are some steps needed to solve it ( as of aug 2017)

1. Please install Devkit and MSYS(now comes with ruby installer)
2. when installing mysql2 gem check if the version supplied from the rubygem repo is actually for your architecture and ruby version e.g. mysql2 0.4.9 does not provide compiled version for windows for ruby 2.4
3. if it is not provided then you need to compile it

   3.a. First download the Mysql c connector from here the zip version is better
   `https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/`
   important please keep in mind of your os architecture for example you must download 64 bit if you want to run it on 64 bit machine

   3.b. Second extract it somewhere and the run this command 
   `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="[your_full_path_to_extracted_mysql_connector]\lib" --with-mysql-include="[your_full_path_to_extracted_mysql_connector]\include"'` 
   please keep in mind of the `'` at the end it is important
4. It should say 1 gem installed
5. Check your connection using this command 
   `rails db:schema:dump` inside your project root directory. you will see a 
   new file in the db folder named schema.rb it means that it is working.
6. You will see specific problems displayed in the console, if any search it in the google you will find answers.

good luck :)